# azure ad cli - how to query multiple parameter from output

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am trying to query my azure ad group and wants to print multiple parameter. However, nothing is working.

Following works to print only `displayName`

```
az ad group member list -g xxx --query [].displayName
```

I want to print `displayName` and `userPrincipalName` as well. However none of the following is working

```
az ad group member list -g xxx--query [].userPrincipalName, [].displayName

az ad group member list -g xxx--query [].{userPrincipalName, displayName}

az ad group member list -g xxx--query []{.userPrincipalName, .displayName}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, you need to specify aliases for each field:

```
az ad group member list -g xxx --query -query "[].{userPrincipalName:userPrincipalName, displayName:displayName}"
```

Note that you need to quote the query.

Actually, there is a second option as well:

```
az ad group member list -g xxx --query "[].[userPrincipalName, displayName]"
```

But the first option returns an array of objects, the second an array of arrays. I'd prefer the first one.

Comment: I am getting error `argument --query: invalid jmespath_type value: '[].{userPrincipalName, displayName}'`

Comment: ah sorry, you need to specify aliases for the fields. look at my updated answer @GaurangShah